# Filter with REGEXMATCH in Google sheet to filter out containing text in cells

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Right now I have these data and I'm trying to filter out the data containing in cell C3, C4, etc.

I have no problem filtering the regexmatch data for 1 cell as shown below

[image]

but I'm unable to do regexmatch for more than 2 cells like so for example, it seems like I'm unable to make the pipework between cells as I'll get parse error, I tried adding in "C3|C4" too.

[image]

and

[image]

The wanted output that I wanted is as below but I could only hardcode the containing text in which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm hoping that I could have some tips to regexmatch the text in more than 1 cell such that it could regexmatch the text in cell C3(Apple) and C4(Pear) and show the wanted output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
=IF(C3<>"", FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A, TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, C3:C4) )), "no input")
```

Or, you may go a step further and match `Apple` or `Pear` as whole words using `\b` word boundaries and a grouping construct around the alternatives:

```
=IF(C3<>"", FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "\b(?:" & TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, C3:C4) & ")\b")), "no input")
```

And if you need to make the search case insensitive, just append `(?i)` at the start:

```
=IF(C3<>"", FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "(?i)\b(?:" & TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, C3:C4) & ")\b")), "no input")
```

See what the [`TEXTJOIN` documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) says:

> Combines the text from multiple strings and/or arrays, with a specifiable delimiter separating the different texts.

So, when you pass `TRUE` as the second argument, you do not have to worry if the range contains empty cells, and the regex won't be ruined by extraneous `|||`.

Test:

[image]

Comment: Oh! I didn't know you could use C3 & "|" C4 instead of just C3|C4, that answered my question! But if I have more cells to filter, will I be adding more lines to it such that **=IF(C3<>"", FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,C3&"|"&C4&"|",&C5)),"no input")** by adding more like C5,C6,C7 etc

Comment: @Lyber OK, I edited the answer with a more generic approach. Use `JOIN("|", C3:C4)`

Comment: Thank you! With the join formula, everything looks much neater. From there I found TEXTJOIN which is able to ignore blanks too

Comment: @Lyber I added that bit to the answer with a link to the docs. Also, as I see it makes a difference, I added a case insensitive variation.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `TEXTJOIN` for dynamic list in C column:

```
=IF(TEXTJOIN( , 1, C3:C)<>"", FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2:A), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, LOWER(C3:C)))), "no input")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! I did try something like **"=FILTER(H2:H,REGEXMATCH(H2:H,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,D2:D20)))"**
however it wasn't case sensitive, your works perfectly!